# Clicks en un Frame

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, lo que pasa es que tengo un botón en mi Frame, ese boton va cambiando el texto cuando se ejecuta,la idea es que cuando el usuario encuentre el objeto cambie de nombre el boton y así, y adicional me de un limite de clicks ,en este caso me los da pero da 11 limites de clic o mas no entiendo porque si lo tengo predefinido turnos ==2 y deberia dar solo dos oportunidades de clic a buscar la imagen.

```
public class Bosque extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private boolean estado;
private int contar;
private String nombre;
private int indicador;
private int turnos;
ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();

public Bosque() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    Niveles ni = new Niveles();
    ni.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
    estado = false;
    Inicio();
}

private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    estado = true;
    Inicio();
    jButton3.setVisible(false);
    datos.add("Arrebal");
    datos.add("Acemila");
    datos.add("Afilo");
    datos.add("Agave");
    datos.add("Ajaraca");
    datos.add("Alcatifa");
    datos.add("Amanal");
    datos.add("Bajel");
    datos.add("Espuela");
    datos.add("Rapa");
    datos.add("Servillana");

    indicador = 1;
    jButton1.setText(datos.get(indicador));
    turnos=0;


}

private void arrebolMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    if (jButton1.getText().equals("Arrebol")) {
        arrebol.setVisible(false);
        nombre = "Arrebol";
        CleanBoton();
        contar += 1;
       puntaje.setText("puntos: "+contar);
      indicador += 1;
        jButton1.setText(datos.get(indicador));
    }else{

turnos++;

        if(turnos==2){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Perdite el nivel hiciste mas intentos de los debidos", "Perdiendo",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        this.dispose();
        }
    }
}

private void Inicio() {
    acemila.setVisible(estado);
    afilo.setVisible(estado);
    agave.setVisible(estado);
    ajaraca.setVisible(estado);
    alcatifa.setVisible(estado);
    amanal.setVisible(estado);
    arrebol.setVisible(estado);
    ave.setVisible(estado);
    bajel.setVisible(estado);
    cabana.setVisible(estado);
    canasta.setVisible(estado);
    caperuza.setVisible(estado);
    cortaarbol.setVisible(estado);
    espuela.setVisible(estado);
    hongo.setVisible(estado);
    jarron.setVisible(estado);
    lena.setVisible(estado);
    lobo.setVisible(estado);
    rapa.setVisible(estado);
    servillana.setVisible(estado);
    tink.setVisible(estado);
    guardabosques.setVisible(estado);
    panda.setVisible(estado);
    lena.setVisible(estado);
    jButton1.setVisible(estado);

}
```

Comment: inicializa turnos desde el momento que declares la variable.

Comment: Ya lo hice y de todas maneras solo me aparece el mensaje a los 9 clicks y aumentan, la idea es que todo sean de a dos

Comment: y antes de funcionar a los 9 clics, que hace? te cuenta las respuestas como buenas?

Comment: No, no las cuenta como buenas, pero da 9 oportunidades y solo deben dar dos,

Comment: `CleanBoton();` sólo limpia el botón? que hace?

Comment: si, solo lo limpia

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62551/discussion-between-paola-and-l-ronquillo).